# Hide fields in a discussion app.

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-fields

I have a wiki page that I am currently editing, and I have a discussion app that has a number of fields on top that I would like to hide to make the page cleaner. What is the best way to go about this? I have included a picture. I am okay with leaving the title field too if needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use F12 to get the id of the element.
[image]

Enter the following script to the page using a Script Editor web part or a Content Editor web part.

```
<style>
#js-listviewthead-WPQ2{display : none;}
</style>
```